# Cryptographic hash golf

Tags: code-golf, cryptography, cops-and-robbers, hashing

> **This contest is over.**
>
> Due to the nature of [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenges, the cops challenge becomes a lot easier when the interest in the associated robbers challenge has diminished. Therefore, while you can still post hash functions, your answer will not get accepted or form part of the leaderboard.

This challenge is a search for the shortest implementation of a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) that is [collision resistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance), i.e., it should be infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash.

As a cop, you try to invent and implement a hash function finding the best compromise between code size and collision resistance. Use too many bytes and another cop will outgolf you!

As a robber, you try to foil the cops' attempts by cracking their functions, proving that they are unsuitable. This will force them to use more bytes to strengthen their algorithms!

### Cops challenge

#### Task

Implement a cryptographic hash function **H : I -> O** of your choice, where **I** is the set of all non-negative integers below 2<sup>2<sup>30</sup></sup> and **O** is the set of all non-negative integers below 2<sup>128</sup>.

You can either implement **H** as an actual function that accepts and returns a single integer, a string representation of an integer or an array of integers or a full program that reads from STDIN and prints to STDOUT in base 10 or 16.

#### Scoring

- **H** that it has to resist the *robbers challenge* defined below.

  If a robber defeats your submission in the first 168 hours after posting it, it is considered *cracked*.
- The implementation of **H** should be as short as possible. *The shortest uncracked submission will be the winner of the cops challenge.*

#### Additional rules

- If you implement **H** as a function, please provide a wrapper to execute the function from within a program that behaves as explained above.
- Please provide at least three test vectors for your program or wrapper (example inputs and their corresponding outputs).
- **H** can be your novel design (preferred) or a well-known algorithm, as long as you implement it yourself. It is forbidden to use any kind in-built hash function, compression function, cipher, PRNG, etc.

  Any built-in commonly used to *implement* hashing functions (e.g., base conversion) is fair game.
- The output of your program or function must be deterministic.
- There should be a free (as in beer) compiler/interpreter that can be run on a x86 or x64 platform or from within a web browser.
- Your program or function should be reasonably efficient and has to hash any message in **I** below 2<sup>2<sup>19</sup></sup> in less than a second.

  For edge cases, the (wall) time taken on my machine (Intel Core i7-3770, 16 GiB of RAM) will be decisive.
- Given the nature of this challenge, it is forbidden to change the code of your answer in any way, whether it alters the output or not.

  If your submission has been cracked (or even if it hasn't), you can post an additional answer.

  If your answer is invalid (e.g., it doesn't comply with the I/O specification), please delete it.

#### Example

> ## Python 2.7, 22 bytes
>
> ```
> def H(M):
>  return M%17
> ```
>
> #### Wrapper
>
> ```
> print H(int(input()))
> ```

### Robbers challenge

#### Task

Crack any of the cops' submissions by posting the following in the [robbers' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51069): two messages **M** and **N** in **I** such that **H(M) = H(N)** and **M ≠ N**.

#### Scoring

- Cracking each cop submissions gains you one point. The robber with the most points wins.

  In the case of a tie, the tied robber that cracked the longest submission wins.

#### Additional rules

- Every cop submission can only be cracked once.
- If a cop submission relies on implementation-defined or undefined behavior, you only have to find a crack that works (verifiably) on your machine.
- Each crack belongs to a separate answer in the robbers' thread.
- Posting an invalid cracking attempt bans you from cracking that particular submission for 30 minutes.
- You may not crack your own submission.

#### Example

> ## Python 2.7, 22 bytes by user8675309
>
> ```
> 1
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> 18
> ```

## Leaderboard

#### Safe submissions

1. [CJam, 21 bytes by eBusiness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51210)
2. [C++, 148 bytes by tucuxi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51155)
3. [C++, 233(?) bytes by Vi.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51089)

#### Uncracked submissions

You can use this Stack Snippet to get a list of not yet cracked answers.

```js
function g(p){$.getJSON('//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/51068/answers?page='+p+'&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36w0DtV5A_ZMzR7bRqt1e',function(s){s.items.map(function(a){var h=$('<div/>').html(a.body).children().first().text();if(!/cracked/i.test(h)&&(typeof a.comments=='undefined'||a.comments.filter(function(b){var c=$('<div/>').html(b.body);return /^cracked/i.test(c.text())||c.find('a').filter(function(){return /cracked/i.test($(this).text())}).length>0}).length==0)){var m=/^\s*((?:[^,(\s]|\s+[^-,(\s])+)\s*(?:[,(]|\s-).*?([0-9]+)/.exec(h);$('<tr/>').append($('<td/>').append($('<a/>').text(m?m[1]:h).attr('href',a.link)),$('<td class="score"/>').text(m?m[2]:'?'),$('<td/>').append($('<a/>').text(a.owner.display_name).attr('href',a.owner.link))).appendTo('#listcontent');}});if(s.length==100)g(p+1);});}g(1);
```

```css
table th, table td {padding: 5px} th {text-align: left} .score {text-align: right} table a {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><table><tr><th>Language</th><th class="score">Length</th><th>User</th></tr><tbody id="listcontent"></tbody></table>
```

Comment: If a hash function erroneously returns numbers greater than 2^128-1, does that invalidate the submission, or would we simply take the result modulo 2^128?

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Yes, you'd have to take the result modulo 2^128.

Comment: I may have been unclear with my first question. I mean if someone actually submits code that *doesn't* take the modulo, is that acceptable (and the robbers condition becomes "H(M) = H(N) (mod 2^128) and M ≠ N") or is it the cop's responsibility to ensure output is in range (which would mean submissions that don't ensure this are invalid).

Comment: I understood, but I didn't express myself very well. The cop submission has to provide an integer in **O**, so you'd have to take the result modulo 2^128 *in your code*.

Comment: Can I implement a function which takes in a string representing the argument in base 10 or 16, or am I required to accept it as a number argument if I use a function?

Comment: @algorithmshark: String representations are fine.

Comment: Is it cheating to just return **I**?

Comment: @Scimonster Doesn't meet the requirements (up to 2^30 bits of input, 128 bits of output)

Comment: So you cannot compete with a language does not support 128 bit (even more 2^30 bit) integers?

Comment: @flawr: As stated in the question, you can represent **I** and **O** as arrays of integers, For **O**, you can choose 1 128-bit integer, 128 1-bit integers or anything in between.

Comment: Doesn't cops and robbers usually go the other way around?

Comment: Where is some Python2 answer I was trying to crack (about circular bitshift)? It suddenly disappeared.

Comment: @Vi. I deleted it because it doesn't conform to the runtime requirements. In fact, I can't compete at all because the runtime requirements are way too strict. Both Pyth and Python are too slow for this challenge. Having to process 130 kilobytes byte-by-byte in less than a second in a slow language is just not possible.

Comment: @haneefmubarak This interpretation of cops and robbers is sort of my fault (because I wrote the first challenge assigning the roles this way round). I've first come across the phrase in internet-security capture-the-flag games, where the cops secure a machine (and the flag in the form of some secret) and the robbers break in to steal it. The metaphor I had in mind was along those lines.

Comment: @orlp: Byte-by-byte being the key here. A block size of 16 bits should solve the speed problem. A block size of 128 bytes would even work with your exec statement. But I don't want the challenge to be too restrictive, so I've changed the speed rule. It only requires integers below `2^(2^19)` under one second now.

Comment: Surely if you want to win this, you should be writing in APL? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)

Comment: Perhaps we could have a rule that submissions must include example hashes, it is quite annoying to have to run the submitters chosen programming language in order to have a result to compare ones cracking implementation against.

Comment: @eBusiness: I had that rule in the original draft, but since the crack has to work only on *some* computer, I edited out. The question now requires at least three test vectors.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for organizing this, it was great fun! (And a big time sink.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, 21 bytes

```
1q3*{i+_E_#*^26_#)%}/
```

Takes a string of bytes as input.

In pseudocode:

```
hash = 1
3 times:
    for i in input:
        hash = hash + i
        hash = hash xor hash * 14^14
        hash = hash mod (26^26 + 1)
output hash
```

Example hashes:

"" (empty string) -> 1
"Test" -> 2607833638733409808360080023081587841
"test" -> 363640467424586895504738713637444713

It may be a bit on the simple side, the output range is only a little more than 122 bits, the triple iteration strengthening is already a bit broken as it does exactly the same thing every time, so input that hash to 1 in the first iteration will be a full break. But it is short, and there is no fun in being too safe.

Comment: Is there an accompanying C version like in the other CJam post?

Comment: @Vi. No, not yet at least. I never dabbled with bigint in C, is there a standard library for that?

Comment: [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: @Vi. Sorry, I'm not going to go on a library safari for this, you'll have to reimplement it in whatever language/library you wish to use for cracking.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/SDzA3JK4

Comment: For the record, this takes 838 ms for `2 2 19 # (` on my machine, making it fast enough to comply with the rules.

Comment: *This submission has remained uncracked for over 168 hours and is now safe.*

Comment: so .... is this Caesar shifting with substitusion by many rounds ?

Comment: @Agawa001 Why would you think so? And no.

Comment: @eBusiness hashing is another form of substitution (as long as it is reversible) , and the information hash(i-1) is used to calculate hash(i) , so there is shifting + substitution ,

Comment: @Agawa001 You are getting your terminology mixed up. It is a triple-pass sponge function hash algorithm. A Caesar cipher is one specific encryption algorithm with no inner state.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 109 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51084/8478), [and again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51086/4162)]

```py
def f(n,h=42,m=2**128):
 while n:h+=n&~-m;n>>=128;h+=h<<10;h^=h>>6;h%=m
 h+=h<<3;h^=h>>11;h+=h<<15;return h%m
```

I tried implementing [Jenkins' one-at-a-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function) function as-is, with the only difference being the seed and the number of bits.

Fun fact: Apparently [Perl used the Jenkins' hash at some point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214270/what-hashing-function-algorithm-does-perl-use).

### Wrapper

```py
print(f(int(input())))
```

### Examples

```py
>>> f(0)
12386682
>>> f(1)
13184902071
>>> f(2**128-1)
132946164914354994014709093274101144634
>>> f(2**128)
13002544814292
>>> f(2**128+1)
13337372262951
>>> f(2**(2**20))
290510273231835581372700072767153076167
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51084/8478)

Comment: [Even more cracked (preimage attack).](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51086/4162)

Answer (score 6):

## C++, 148 bytes

```cpp
typedef __uint128_t U;U h(char*b,U n,U&o){U a=0x243f6a8885a308d,p=0x100000001b3;for(o=a;n--;)for(U i=27;--i;){o=(o<<i)|(o>>(128-i));o*=p;o^=b[n];}}
```

[__uint128_t](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#g_t_005f_005fint128) is a GCC extension, and works as expected. The hash is based on iterating [FNV hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) (I've borrowed their prime, although `a` is the first digits of Pi in hex) with a [sha1-like](https://code.google.com/p/smallsha1/source/browse/trunk/sha1.cpp?spec=svn2&r=2) rotation at the start of each iteration. Compiling with `-O3`, hashing a 10MB file takes under 2 seconds, so there is still margin for upping the iterations in the inner loop - but I'm feeling generous today.

De-uglified (changed variable names, added comments, whitespace and a pair of braces) for your cracking pleasure:

```cpp
typedef __uint128_t U;
U h(char* input, U inputLength, U &output){
    U a=0x243f6a8885a308d,p=0x100000001b3;    
    for(output=a;inputLength--;) {   // initialize output, consume input
        for(U i=27;--i;) {                          // evil inner loop
            output = (output<<i)|(output>>(128-i)); // variable roll 
            output *= p;                            // FNV hash steps
            output ^= input[inputLength];        
        }
    }
    // computed hash now available in output
}
```

Golfing suggestions are welcome (even if I don't get to improve the code based on them).

**edit:** fixed typos in de-uglified code (golfed version remains unchanged).

Comment: `o` seems to be uninitialized. Where `output` is declared? Or maybe `o` is `output`?

Comment: The same for `n`. Have you actually checked the "de-uglified" code to run?

Comment: Started the bruteforcer...

Comment: Even 3-round version is not easy.

Comment: @Vi. Fixed de-uglified version -- sorry for not checking it better.  I'm proud of that inner loop; `U i=81;i-=3` could have been even more vile, without significant runtime costs.

Comment: What do the `d` and `b3` integer suffixes mean? I don't know C well, so I'm trying to translate it. Also, how are you using a 16-bit datatype when the input can have up to 134,217,728 bytes?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 `d` and `b3` are not suffixes, just part of the hex. `char` is 8-bit.  `char *` is a pointer to a `char` (or in this case, an array of `char`s), and can be treated like an array (see `input[inputLength]`).

Comment: @g.rocket Hex fail... I know  most of the syntax, though, such as pointers and `char`s.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I was just pointing out that what you called a "16-bit datatype" was actually an array of 8-bit datatypes.  I might have misunderstood which you were referring to as the "16-bit datatype."

Comment: @g.rocket Thanks, meant 16-byte and forgot that it's just for the output... Also, do the `for` loops stop at 1 or 0?

Comment: for-loops stop when the center condition is false;  for( _init_ ; _cond_ ; _post_ ) _body_ is roughly equivalent to _init_ ; while( _cond_ ) { _body_ ;  _post_ }

Comment: @tucuxi I know, it's just that I was confused from the pre- and post-decrements (I know what they are.)

Comment: *This submission has remained uncracked for over 168 hours and is now safe.*

Answer (score 5):

### C++, 182 characters (+ about 51 characters of boilerplate)

```cpp
h=0xC0CC3051F486B191;j=0x9A318B5A176B8125;char q=0;for(int i=0;i<l;++i){char w=buf[i];h+=((w<<27)*257);j^=(h+0x5233);h+=0xAA02129953CC12C3*(j>>32);j^=(w+0x134)*(q-0x16C552F34);q=w;}
```

Boilerplate:

```cpp
void hash(const unsigned char* buf, size_t len, unsigned long long *hash1, unsigned long long *hash2)
{
    unsigned long long &h=*hash1;
    unsigned long long &j=*hash2;
    size_t l = len;
    const unsigned char* b = buf;

    // code here
}
```

### Runnable program with a golfed function

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

// The next line is 227 characters long
int hash(char*b,int l,long long&h,long long&j){h=0xC0CC3051F486B191;j=0x9A318B5A176B8125;char q=0;for(int i=0;i<l;++i){char w=b[i];h+=((w<<27)*257);j^=(h+0x5233);h+=0xAA02129953CC12C3*(j>>32);j^=(w+0x134)*(q-0x16C552F34);q=w;}}

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    int l  = fread(buf, 1, 1024, stdin);
    long long q, w;
    hash(buf, l, q, w);
    printf("%016llX%016llX\n", q, w);
}
```

Comment: I think the function declaration etc. counts towards the character count.

Comment: @Ypnypn, counted characters in a golfed down function declaration.

Comment: What is the output hash? I am assuming it is  ((h<<64)|j).

Comment: Yes. Or just a pair of 64-bit numbers. I found out about `__uint128_t` only after implemeting this.

Comment: Tough to crack. If it lasts the night, I'll submit it as SHA-4 
:-P

Comment: @tucuxi, It isn't broken by my bruteforcer in 10 hours (and counting). I don't think any 128-bit hash can be SHA-4. Actually I just mashed in some random constrants, arithmetic and bit operators together and tested it for collisions.

Comment: I had a hunch concerning sequences of 0x00 bytes (which are really quick to hash, since you can set `w = q = 0` and there's no need to actually generate the sequences themselves). No luck there either.

Comment: Would it be okay if you posted some example runs? Also, what is the expected input format - a string of any characters, specifically digit characters 0-9, or...?

Comment: @Sp3000, Input is a byte buffer. Tests: `"" -> C0CC3051F486B1919A318B5A176B8125`, `"\x00"-> DB768C65B8B6F0F2A50245424A6FB791"`, `"A" -> DB768C65C0B6F0F2A50246E6CC0EBBDD`, `"ABC" -> 3312D717E8D481501F9FBC2DA342116A`.

Comment: *This submission has remained uncracked for over 168 hours and is now safe.*

Comment: @Vi.: Could you please provide the full function (golfed boilerplate and all)?

Comment: @Dennis, https://gist.github.com/vi/248db6d2d2bdc26d66cc . Check the tests above.

Comment: I meant the *golfed* boilerplate. Since you claim a score of 233, that 233 byte code should be included in your answer.

Comment: @Dennis, Done.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 44 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51169/25180)]

```
lW%600/_z]{JfbDbGK#%GC#[md\]}%z~Bb4G#%\+GC#b
```

Input is in base 10.

CJam is slow. I hope it runs in 1 second in some computer...

#### Explanations

```
lW%600/            e# Reverse, and split into chunks with size 600.
_z                 e# Duplicate and swap the two dimensions.
]{                 e# For both versions or the array:
    JfbDb          e# Sum of S[i][j]*13^i*19^j, where S is the character values,
                   e# and the indices are from right to left, starting at 0.
    GK#%GC#[md\]   e# Get the last 32+48 bits.
}%
z~                 e# Say the results are A, B, C, D, where A and C are 32 bits.
Bb4G#%             e# E = the last 32 bits of A * 11 + C.
\+GC#b             e# Output E, B, D concatenated in binary.
```

Well, the two dimensional things seemed to be a weakness... It was intended to make some slow calculations faster at the beginning. But it cannot run in a second no matter what I do, so I removed the slow code finally.

It should be also better if I have used binary bits and higher bases.

### C version

```c
__uint128_t hash(unsigned char* s){
    __uint128_t a=0,b=0;
    __uint128_t ar=0;
    __uint128_t v[600];
    int l=0,j=strlen(s);
    memset(v,0,sizeof v);
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        if(i%600)
            ar*=19;
        else{
            a=(a+ar)*13;
            ar=0;
        }
        if(i%600>l)
            l=i%600;
        v[i%600]=v[i%600]*19+s[j-i-1];
        ar+=s[j-i-1];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=l;i++)
        b=b*13+v[i];
    a+=ar;
    return (((a>>48)*11+(b>>48))<<96)
        +((a&0xffffffffffffull)<<48)
        +(b&0xffffffffffffull);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a description? Not everyone knows CJam.

Comment: @orlp Edited...

Comment: This takes 0.4 s on my computer, so it's well within the allowed range.

Comment: What is A, B, C and so on? Some matrices? Which dimensions? Can it be easily implemented in C?

Comment: A and B are the last 80 bits of the result using the original dimension order. A is 32 bit, to the left of B, which is 48 bit. C and D are similar but using the swapped dimension order. They are numbers. Changed the matrix to S to reduce confusion.

Comment: (I though about using my collision detector on this, but incompatibility with C is a stopper)

Comment: @Vi. I think the only problem (if a C code doesn't match the result) would be the initial step of splitting the reversed base 10 string, and aligning with the rightmost digit. Others are straightforward.

Comment: Slowness of the hash (or slowness of CJam startup) protects the it from being brufeforced.

Comment: Started the bruteforcer...

Comment: If input is in base 10, shouldn't `0` and `00` hash to the same value?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Indeed it should be better have been in binary. But since I already specified it to be in decimal (due to some weakness I spotted before posting), let's say there is only one valid representation for each number, which doesn't have extra leading zeros.

Comment: The bruteforcer can't find anything in 35 CPU hours on i5..

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51169/21487), I believe.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 8 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51075/31625)

```
sv_`.lhQ
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sv_%60.lhQ&input=123456789&debug=0)

A bit of a silly answer, I'll explain how it works because most people can't read Pyth. This takes the natural log of one plus the input, and then converts that to a string. That string is reversed, and then evaluated and then converted to an integer.

A python translation would look like:

```
import math
n = eval(input()) + 1
rev = str(math.log(n))[::-1]
print(int(eval(rev)))
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51075/21487)?

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 216 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51134/21487)]

```py
def f(m):
 h=1;p=[2]+[n for n in range(2,102)if 2**n%n==2];l=len(bin(m))-2;*b,=map(int,bin((l<<(l+25)//26*26)+m)[2:])
 while b:
  h*=h
  for P in p:
   if b:h=h*P**b.pop()%0xb6ee45a9012d1718f626305a971e6a21
 return h
```

Due to an incompatibility with the spec I can think of at least one *slight* vulnerability, but other than that I think this is at least brute-force proof. I've checked the first 10 million hashes, among other things.

In terms of golf this would be shorter in Python 2, but I've sacrificed some bytes for efficiency (since it's probably not going to win anyway).

Edit: This was my attempt at implementing the [Very Smooth Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_smooth_hash), but unfortunately 128-bits was far too small.

### Wrapper

```py
print(f(int(input())))
```

### Examples

```py
>>> f(0)
2
>>> f(123456789)
228513724611896947508835241717884330242
>>> f(2**(2**19)-1)
186113086034861070379984115740337348649
>>> f(2**(2**19))
1336078
```

### Code explanation

```py
def f(m):
 h=1                                             # Start hash at 1
 p=[2]+[n for n in range(2,102)if 2**n%n==2]     # p = primes from 2 to 101
 l=len(bin(m))-2                                 # l = bit-length of m (input)
 *b,=map(int,bin((l<<(l+25)//26*26)+m)[2:])      # Convert bits to list, padding to
                                                 # a multiple of 26 then adding the
                                                 # bit-length at the front

 while b:                                        # For each round
  h*=h                                           # Square the hash
  for P in p:                                    # For each prime in 2 ... 101
   if b:h=(h*P**b.pop()                          # Multiply by prime^bit, popping
                                                 # the bit from the back of the list
           %0xb6ee45a9012d1718f626305a971e6a21)  # Take mod large number

 return h                                        # Return hash
```

An example of the padding for `f(6)`:

```py
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

(len 3)(------------------ 23 zeroes for padding -------------------------)(input 6)
       (---------------------------- length 26 total ------------------------------)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51134/30688)

Answer (score 4):

## C, 87 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51174/11006)]

This is the complete program; no wrapper required. Accepts binary input via stdin, and outputs a hexadecimal hash to stdout.

```c
c;p;q;main(){while((c=getchar())+1)p=p*'foo+'+q+c,q=q*'bar/'+p;printf("%08x%08x",p,q);}
```

This only calculates a 64-bit hash, so I'm taking a bit of a gamble here.

In case anyone's wondering, the two constants `'foo+'` and `'bar/'` are the prime numbers 1718578987 and 1650553391.

---

#### Examples:

Ignores leading zeroes:

```c
echo -ne '\x00\x00\x00\x00' |./hash
0000000000000000
```

Single-byte inputs:

```c
echo -ne '\x01' |./hash
0000000100000001
echo -ne '\xff' |./hash
000000ff000000ff
```

Multi-byte inputs:

```c
echo -ne '\x01\x01' |./hash
666f6f2dc8d0e15c
echo -ne 'Hello, World' |./hash
04f1a7412b17b86c
```

Comment: How would it behave with 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' and 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'?

Comment: I was going to remove the comment, since I found out for myself. But thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: `foo|` (d5c9bef71d4f5d1b) and ``foo\`` (d5c9bef71d4f5d1b) produce **VERY** similar hashes.

Comment: Try `~~`, `~^` and ``~\``. They differ by 2. Everytime you add 1 bit, it adds 2 at position 8 and 16. By the way, how would `~~~~~~~~~~~~~` and `~~~~~~~~~~~~~\0` behave? (can't test the `\0` on ideone.com)

Comment: What about `~~~~~~~~~~~~~` and `~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF`? Since you add 1 to each char, `\xFF` should overlap to `0`. Thus, `p*'foo+'+q+c` would be `p*'foo+'+q+0`, breaking your code.

Comment: Still different. I'm not incrementing `c` — check the parentheses.

Comment: Broke it!!! `\x00` and `\x00\x00`!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24362/discussion-between-squeamish-ossifrage-and-ismael-miguel).

Comment: Based on the chat comments, I believe this is still not cracked yet? Just double checking, because the upvoted comment might be confusing to those who are skimming for uncracked hashes.

Comment: @Sp3000 Not yet cracked

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51174/7773

Answer (score 3):

## J - 39 bytes - [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51093/5138)

Function taking a string as input and returning an integer < 2<sup>128</sup>. I am assuming we have to name our function to be valid, so drop another 3 chars from the count if we can submit anonymous functions.

```
H=:_8(".p:@+5,9:)a\(a=.(2^128x)&|@^/@)]
```

For those of you that don't read hieroglyphics, here's a rundown of what I'm doing.

- `a=.(2^128x)&|@^/@` This is a subroutine* which takes an array of numbers, and then treats it as a power tower, where exponentiation is taken mod 2<sup>128</sup>. By "power tower", I mean if you gave it the input `3 4 5 6`, it would calculate `3 ^ (4 ^ (5 ^ 6))`.
- `(".p:@+5,9:)a` This function takes a string, converts it to the number *N*, and then calculates the (*n*+5)-th and (*n*+9)-th prime numbers, and then throws the `a` from before on it. That is, we find `p(n+5) ^ p(n+9)` mod 2<sup>128</sup> where `p(k)` is the `k`-th prime.
- `H=:_8...\(a...)]` Perform the above function on 8-character subblocks of the input, and then `a` all the results together and call the resulting hash function `H`. I use 8 characters because J's "`k`-th prime" function fails when `p(k)` > 2<sup>31</sup>, i.e. `k=105097564` is the largest safe `k`.

Have some sample outputs. You can try this yourself online at [tryj.tk](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=H%3D%3A_8%28%22.p%3A%40%2B5%2C9%3A%29a%5C%28a%3D.%282%5E128x%29%26%7C%40%5E%2F%40%29%5D), but I really recommend doing this at home by downloading the interpreter from [Jsoftware](http://www.jsoftware.com/stable.htm).

```
   H=:_8(".p:@+5,9:)a\(a=.(2^128x)&|@^/@)]
   H '88'
278718804776827770823441490977679256075
   H '0'
201538126434611150798503956371773
   H '1'
139288917338851014461418017489467720433
   H '2'
286827977638262502014244740270529967555
   H '3'
295470173585320512295453937212042446551
   30$'0123456789'  NB. a 30 character string
012345678901234567890123456789
   H 30$'0123456789'
75387099856019963684383893584499026337
   H 80$'0123456789'
268423413606061336240992836334135810465
```

* Technically, it's not a function in and of itself, it attaches to other functions and acts on their output. But this is a semantic issue of J, not a conceptual difference: the program flow is as I described it above.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51093/21487)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>299</s> <s>291</s> 282 bytes, [cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51069/cryptographic-hash-golf-robbers/51088#51088)

```java
import java.math.*;class H{public static void main(String[]a){BigInteger i=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextBigInteger();System.out.print(BigInteger.valueOf(i.bitCount()*i.bitLength()+1).add(i.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE))).modPow(i,BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(128)));}}
```

Does some operations on BigIntegers, then takes the result modulo 2<sup>128</sup>.

Comment: How do I run this? Ideone refuses to compile it.

Comment: You can run it on Ideone by renaming the class to "Main" or removing the first "public" keyword (but NOT the second one). Either one will work.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51088/8478)

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Why not remove the first `public` yourself, saving 7 chars?

Comment: @immibis Because then I don't think it would work right on Eclipse. I'll try it though. EDIT: I guess it does. That's a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 118 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51069/cryptographic-hash-golf-robbers/51160#51160)]

```py
def H(I):
    o=0;n=3;M=1<<128
    for c in I:i=ord(c);o=(o<<i^o^i^n^0x9bb90058bcf52d3276a7bf07bcb279b7)%M;n=n*n%M
    return o
```

Indentation is a single tab. Simple hash, haven't really tested it thoroughly yet.

Call as follows:

```py
print(H("123456789"))
```

result: `73117705077050518159191803746489514685`

Comment: How should the input integer be converted to a string to use in your algorithm?

Comment: @feersum base-10 string is what I tested. It doesn't use anything but `ord(c)` though, so really, any string will do :) (except things like nul chars, I think those make hash collisions really easy. So stick with a 0-9 string.)

Comment: Broke it:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51160/41288. Started out by observing that strings like "10000" and "20000" produce very close hashes. Started to play around with more and more zeroes, and after 128 or so, any digit + k*4 zeroes repeats returns the same hash regardless of k.

Comment: @tucuxi Already thought it shouldn't bee _too_ hard; glad that is wasn't trivial but that someone broke it anyway. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 239 bytes

My very first code golf! [*Please be gentle*]

```cpp
#define r(a,b) ((a<<b)|(a>>(64-b)))
typedef uint64_t I;I f(I*q, I n, I&h){h=0;for(I i=n;--i;)h=r(h^(r(q[i]*0x87c37b91114253d5,31)*0x4cf5ad432745937f),31)*5+0x52dce729;h^=(h>>33)*0xff51afd7ed558ccd;h^=(h>>33)*0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;h^=(h>>33);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```cpp
I f(I* q, I n, I& h) // input, length and output
{
    h = 0; // initialize hashes
    for (I i=n;--i;)
    {
        q[i] *= 0x87c37b91114253d5;
        q[i]  = rotl(q[i], 31);
        q[i] *= 0x4cf5ad432745937f;

        h ^= q[i]; // merge the block with hash

        h *= rotl(h, 31);
        h = h * 5 + 0x52dce729;
    }
    h ^= h>>33;
    h *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
    h ^= h>>33;
    h *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53; // avalanche!
    h ^= h>>33;
}
```

Not the best hash, and definitely not the shortest code in existence. Accepting golfing tips and hoping to improve!

### Wrapper

Probably not the best in the world, but a wrapper nonetheless

```cpp
I input[500];

int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    memcpy(input, s.c_str(), s.length());
    I output;
    f(input, 500, output);
    cout << hex << output << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks solid, but with 64 bits, it may be subject to brute-forcing. There is about a 50% chance to find a collision in ~sqrt(n) tests (from among n total outputs);  2^32 tries is not that much for a modern pc.

Comment: Wrapper lacks header inclusions and in general leads to many equal hashes.

Comment: Provide some hash samples. For me both "3" and "33" lead to 481c27f26cba06cf (using this wrapper).

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51215/41288 . I suspect right before @Vi. found out why so many hashes were equal.

Comment: Proper collision (without bug using): `printf '33333333\x40\xF3\x32\xD6\x56\x91\xCA\x66' | ./hash7_` -> `a4baea17243177fd`; `printf '33333333\x77\x39\xF3\x82\x93\xDE\xA7\x2F' | ./hash7_` -> `a4baea17243177fd`. The bruteforcer finds collisions here much faster compared to in other 64-bit hash here.

Comment: Much of the strength of multiplication in a hash relies on the multiplicative constants being prime; in this case, only `0xff51afd7ed558ccd` happens to be a prime.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 128 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51216/11006)]

```c
p;q;r;s;main(c){while((c=getchar())+1)p=p*'foo+'+s^c,q=q*'bar/'+p,r=r*'qux3'^q,s=s*'zipO'+p;printf("%08x%08x%08x%08x",p,q,r,s);}
```

This is more or less the same algorithm as [my last effort](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51146/11006) [(cracked by Vi.)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51174/11006), but now has enough hamster wheels to generate proper 128-bit hashes.

The four prime constants in the code are as follows:

```c
'foo+' = 1718578987
'bar/' = 1650553391
'qux3' = 1903523891
'zipO' = 2053730383
```

As before, this is a complete program with no need for a wrapper. The integer **I** is input via stdin as raw binary data (big-endian), and the hash **O** is printed in hex to stdout. Leading zeroes in **I** are ignored.

### Examples:

```c
echo -ne '\x00' |./hash
00000000000000000000000000000000
echo -ne '\x00\x00' |./hash
00000000000000000000000000000000
echo -ne '\x01' |./hash
00000001000000010000000100000001
echo -ne 'A' |./hash
00000041000000410000004100000041
echo -ne '\x01\x01' |./hash
666f6f2dc8d0e15cb9a5996fe0d8df7c
echo -ne 'Hello, World' |./hash
da0ba2857116440a9bee5bb70d58cd6a
```

Comment: Cracked http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51216/101

Comment: Didn't your example show a collision right there (the first two)?

Comment: @mbomb007 No. The input is a number between 0 and 2^(2^30). 0x00 and 0x0000 are both equal to zero, so they produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 122 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51354/101)]

```
long long x,y,p;main(c){for(c=9;c|p%97;c=getchar()+1)for(++p;c--;)x=x*'[3QQ'+p,y^=x^=y^=c*x;printf("%016llx%016llx",x,y);}
```

Nested loops, half-assed LCGs, and variable swapping.  What's not to love?

Here's a ungolf'd version to play around with:

```
long long x,y,p;

int main(int c){
    // Start with a small number of iterations to
    //   get the state hashes good and mixed because initializing takes space
    // Then, until we reach the end of input (EOF+1 == 0)
    //   and a position that's a multiple of 97
    for (c=9;c|p%97;c=getchar()+1) {

        // For each input c(haracter) ASCII value, iterate down to zero
        for (++p;c--;) {

            // x will act like a LCG with a prime multiple
            //   partially affected by the current input position
            // The string '[3QQ' is the prime number 0x5B335151
            x=x*'[3QQ'+p;

            // Mix the result of x with the decrementing character
            y^=c*x;

            // Swap the x and y buffers
            y^=x^=y;
        }
    }

    // Full 128-bit output
    printf("%016llx%016llx",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a fully self-contains program that reads from STDIN and prints to STDOUT.

Example:

```
> echo -n "Hello world" | ./golfhash
b3faef341f70c5ad6eed4c33e1b55ca7

> echo -n "" | ./golfhash
69c761806803f70154a7f816eb3835fb

> echo -n "a" | ./golfhash
5f0e7e5303cfcc5ecb644cddc90547ed

> echo -n "c" | ./golfhash
e64e173ed4415f7dae81aae0137c47e5
```

In some simple benchmarks, it hashes around 3MB/s of text data.  The hash speed depends on the input data itself, so that should probably be taken into consideration.

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51354/101

Answer (score 1):

## **C, 134 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51095/11006)**

This is complete C program.

```c
long long i=0,a=0,e=1,v,r;main(){for(;i++<323228500;r=(e?(scanf("%c",&v),e=v>'/'&&v<':',v):(a=(a+1)*7)*(7+r)));printf("0x%llx\n", r);}
```

What it does:
The idea is to take input as byte array and append pseudo random (but deterministic) bytes at the end to make the length equal to about 2<sup>2<sup>30</sup></sup> (a bit more).
The implementation reads input byte by byte and starts using pseudo random data when it finds the first character that isn't a digit.

As builtin PRNG isn't allowed I implemented it myself.

There is undefined/implementation defined behavior that makes the code shorter (the final value should be unsigned, and I should use different types for different values).
And I couldn't use 128 bit values in C.
Less obfuscated version:

```c
long long i = 0, prand = 0, notEndOfInput = 1, in, hash;

main() {
    for (; i++ < 323228500;) {
        if (notEndOfInput) {
            scanf("%c", &in);
            notEndOfInput = in >= '0' && in <= '9';
            hash = in;
        } else {
            prand = (prand + 1)*7;
            hash = prand*(7 + hash);
        }
    }
    printf("0x%llx\n", hash);
}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51095/11006)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 4.1, 66 bytes [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51121/14732)]

I'm just warming up.

I hope you find this insteresting.

```
<?for($l=strlen($b.=$a*1);$i<40;$o.=+$b[+$i]^"$a"/$a,$i++);echo$o;
```

I've tried it numbers as large as 999999999999999999999999999.
The output seemed to be within the 2<sup>128</sup> range.

---

PHP 4.1 is required because of the [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) directive.

It works by automatically creating local variables from the session, POST, GET, REQUEST and cookies.

It uses the key `a`. (E.G.: access over `http://localhost/file.php?a=<number>`).

If you want to test it with PHP 4.2 and newer, try this:

```
<?for($l=strlen($b.=$a=$_REQUEST['a']*1);$i<40;$o.=+$b[+$i]^"$a"/$a,$i++);echo$o;
```

This version only works with POST and GET.

---

Example output:

```
0 -> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
9 -> 8111111111111111111111111111111111111111
9999 -> 8888111111111111111111111111111111111111
1234567890 -> 0325476981111111111111111111111111111111
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 -> 0111191111111111111111111111111111111111
```

(I assure you that there are numbers that produce the same hash).

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51121/7773

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.X - 139 bytes** [[[Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51180/36885)]]

This is quite similar to all the other (LOOP,XOR,SHIFT,ADD) hashes out here. Come get your points robbers ;) I'll make a harder one after this one is solved.

```
M=2**128
def H(I):
 A=[1337,8917,14491,71917];O=M-I%M
 for z in range(73):
  O^=A[z%4]**(9+I%9);O>>=3;O+=9+I**(A[z%4]%A[O%4]);O%=M
 return O
```

Wrapper (expects one argument in base-16 also known as hexadecimal):

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
 print hex(H(long(sys.argv[1], 16)))[2:][:-1].upper()
```

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51180/36885

Comment: Also, I am not sure that this entry meets the OP's spec, since on my machine the function takes multiple seconds on large inputs.  For example, `H(2**(2**10))` took around 8 or 9 seconds, while `H(2**(2**12))` took around 29 seconds and `H(2**(2**14))` took over two minutes.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I obviously should have tested the timing for larger inputs. Also, I appear to have forgot to run my own test after that shift was added. The original version was without shift (before posting) and it was passing my "no collisions in the first 100000 integers" test :/

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.7 - 161 bytes [[[Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51197/25180)]]**

Well since I managed to change my first hash function into an useless version before posting it, I think I will post another version of a similar structure. This time I tested it against trivial collisions and I tested most of the possible input magnitudes for speed.

```
A=2**128;B=[3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
def H(i):
 o=i/A
 for r in range(9+B[i%7]):
  v=B[i%7];i=(i+o)/2;o=o>>v|o<<128-v;o+=(9+o%6)**B[r%6];o^=i%(B[r%6]*v);o%=A
 return o
```

Wrapper (not counted in the bytecount)

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
 arg = long(sys.argv[1].strip(), 16)
 print hex(H(arg))[2:][:-1].upper()
```

Run example (input is always a hexadecimal number):

```
$ python crypt2.py 1
3984F42BC8371703DB8614A78581A167
$ python crypt2.py 10
589F1156882C1EA197597C9BF95B9D78
$ python crypt2.py 100
335920C70837FAF2905657F85CBC6FEA
$ python crypt2.py 1000
B2686CA7CAD9FC323ABF9BD695E8B013
$ python crypt2.py 1000AAAA
8B8959B3DB0906CE440CD44CC62B52DB
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51197/25180).

Comment: Well done jimmy :)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 90 Bytes

```
def H(s);i=823542;s.each_byte{|x|i=(i*(x+1)+s.length).to_s.reverse.to_i%(2**128)};i;end
```

A highly random hash algorithm I made up without looking at any real hashes...no idea if it is good. it takes a string as input.

#### Wrapper:

```
def buildString(i)
  if(i>255)
    buildString(i/256)+(i%256).chr
  else
    i.chr
  end
end 
puts H buildString gets
```

Comment: Could you please provide the wrapper the question requires?

Comment: What's the input format? I tried with a number but it says ``comparison of String with 255 failed (ArgumentError)``.

Comment: H takes a string, Build string takes the number required by the OP and transforms it to a string.

Comment: I think you need a `gets.to_i` in the wrapper.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51250/25180).

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 89 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51081/8478)

```mathematica
Last@CellularAutomaton[(a=Mod)[#^2,256],{#~IntegerDigits~2,0},{#~a~99,128}]~FromDigits~2&
```

Not the shortest.

Comment: How do you run this without Mathematica? "There should be a free (as in beer) compiler/interpreter that can be run on a x86 or x64 platform or from within a web browser."

Comment: @MartinBüttner https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51081/8478)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 79 Bytes (cracked. With a comment):

```php
echo (('.'.str_replace('.',M_E*$i,$i/pi()))*substr(pi(),2,$i%20))+deg2rad($i);
```

This does alot of scary things via type-conversions in php, which makes it hard to predict ;) (or at least I hope so). It's not the shortest or most unreadable answer, however.

To run it you can use [PHP4 and register globals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51118/32753) (with ?i=123) or use the commandline:

```php
php -r "$i = 123.45; echo (('.'.str_replace('.',M_E*$i,$i/pi()))*substr(pi(),2,$i%20))+deg2rad($i);"
```

Comment: The hash's output value looks floating-point. And It's the same for 3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 and 3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 393 bytes [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51277/11180)

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[]a){int l=a[0].Length;l=l%8==0?l/8:l/8+1;var b=new byte[l][];for(int i=0;i<l;i++){b[i]=new byte[8];};int j=l-1,k=7;for(int i=0;i<a[0].Length;i++){b[j][k]=Convert.ToByte(""+a[0][i],16);k--;if((i+1)%8==0){j--;k=7;}}var c=0xcbf29ce484222325;for(int i=0;i<l;i++){for(int o=0;o<8;o++){c^=b[i][o];c*=0x100000001b3;}}Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("X"));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System;
class P
{
    static void Main(string[]a)
    {
      int l = a[0].Length;
      l = l % 8 == 0 ? l / 8 : l / 8 + 1;
      var b = new byte[l][];
      for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) { b[i] = new byte[8]; };
      int j = l-1, k = 7;
      for (int i = 0; i < a[0].Length; i++)
      {
        b[j][k] = Convert.ToByte(""+a[0][i], 16);
        k--;
        if((i+1) % 8 == 0)
        {
          j--;
          k = 7;
        }
      }
      var c = 0xcbf29ce484222325;
      for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
      {
        for (int o = 0; o < 8; o++)
        {
          c ^= b[i][o];
          c *= 0x100000001b3;
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("X"));
    }
}
```

I have never touched cryptography or hashing in my life, so be gentle :)

It's a simple implementation of an [FNV-1a](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html) hash with some array pivoting on the input. I am sure there is a better way of doing this but this is the best I could do.

It might use a bit of memory on long inputs.

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51277/101 On top of having faulty padding, this is not a cryptographic hash, there is so many ways to break it.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 115 bytes [[Cracked already!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51316/25180)]

OK, here's my last effort. Only 115 bytes because the final newline isn't required.

```Python
h,m,s=1,0,raw_input()
for c in[9+int(s[x:x+197])for x in range(0,len(s),197)]:h+=pow(c,257,99**99+52)
print h%4**64
```

This is a complete program that inputs a decimal integer on stdin and prints a decimal hash value on stdout. Extra leading zeroes will result in different hash values, so I'll just assume that the input doesn't have any.

This works by stuffing 197-digit chunks of the input number through a modular exponentiation. Unlike some languages, the `int()` function always defaults to base 10, so `int('077')` is 77, not 63.

#### Sample outputs:

```
$ python hash.py <<<"0"
340076608891873865874583117084537586383

$ python hash.py <<<"1"
113151740989667135385395820806955292270

$ python hash.py <<<"2"
306634563913148482696255393435459032089

$ python hash.py <<<"42"
321865481646913829448911631298776772679

$ time python hash.py <<<`python <<<"print 2**(2**19)"`
233526113491758434358093601138224122227

real    0m0.890s   <-- (Close, but fast enough)
user    0m0.860s
sys     0m0.027s
```

Comment: It didn't use the order of blocks... [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51316/25180).

Comment: Ugh. I give in :-(