# Cryptographic hash golf (robbers)

Tags: code-golf, cryptography, cops-and-robbers, hashing

> **This contest is over.**
>
> There are no remaining crackable answer in the cops challenge.

## Companion thread of [Cryptographic hash golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51068)

As a reminder, here are the rules for robbers from the main challenge:

> #### Task
>
> Crack any of the cops' submissions by posting the following in the
>   robbers' thread: two messages **M** and **N** in **I** such that
>   **H(M) = H(N)** and **M ≠ N**.
>
> #### Scoring
>
> Cracking each cop submissions gains you one point. The robber with the most points wins.
>
> In the case of a tie, the tied robber that cracked the longest
>   submission wins.
>
> #### Additional rules
>
> - Every cop submission can only be cracked once.
> - If a cop submission relies on implementation-defined or undefined behavior, you only have to find a crack that works (verifiably) on
>     your machine.
> - Each crack belongs to a separate answer in the robbers' thread.
> - Posting an invalid cracking attempt bans you from cracking that particular submission for 30 minutes.
> - You may not crack your own submission.
>
> #### Example
>
> > ## Python 2.7, 22 bytes by user8675309
> >
> > ```
> > 1
> > ```
> >
> > and
> >
> > ```
> > 18
> > ```

#### Leaderboard

1. eBusiness: 3 cracks, 393 bytes
2. Martin Büttner: 3 cracks, 299 bytes
3. jimmy23013: 3 cracks, 161 bytes
4. Sp3000: 3 cracks, 44 bytes
5. tucuxi: 2 cracks, 239 bytes
6. Vi.: 2 cracks, 87 bytes
7. feersum: 1 crack, 216 bytes
8. mathmandan: 1 crack, 139 bytes
9. squeamish ossifrage: 1 crack, 134 bytes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [C, 122 bytes - by: Mr. Llama](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51224/101)

```
bmaj8PCosFLAJjeHaevvvchnJedmg2iujpePOPivI2x2asw0yKa2eA15xvFJMFe82RGIcdlvxyaAPRuDuJhFjbh78BFsnCufJkarwEyKa0azHxccw5qegpcP9yaO0FKoohanxgiAfK1Lqwba51bKtjacbvdjMmcBkiv8kd62sBd98c4twa98sgj3iPh7nkP4
rlaejTPrua1DhBdg0jrIoDBi8fc1GIJAigivIGaxs1OmfPcctNadK3HErvzPLCeDPD8fkMNPCBcIwuoGfEHegOfk9k9pwktslqaBenaati1uNthMiyk9ndpy7gdIz88iot6A09cbNeIMheyjBvbeegL7aGp7mCb91hCxnvgV5abfImrPfLbrbraAsN6loJgh
```

Both strings hash to `bb66000000000000d698000000000000`

Just like "C, 128 bytes - by: squeamish ossifrage" the higher order bits never influence the lower order bits, this can be exploited.

#### Code

Visual C++, uses "[unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753468/305545)" string operations

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

long long x, y;

//Original hash function (not used for cracking).
void h(char inp[]){
    long long c;
    int index = 0;
    int len = strlen(inp);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    long long p = 0;
    for (c = 9; c ; c = (index<len?inp[index++]:-1) + 1) {
        for (++p; c--;) {
            x = x*'[3QQ' + p;
            y ^= c*x;
            y ^= x ^= y;
        }
    }
    printf("%016llx%016llx\n", x, y);
}

//Partial hash, takes a string and a starting point in the stream.
//The byte 0x08 must be prepended to a string in order to produce a full legal hash.
void hp(char inp[],long long p){
    long long c;
    int index = 0;
    int len = strlen(inp);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    for (index = 0; index<len; index++) {
        c = inp[index] + 1;
        for (++p; c--;) {
            x = x*'[3QQ' + p;
            y ^= c*x;
            y ^= x ^= y;
        }
    }
}

//Reverse partial hash, backtracks the inner state.
void hprev(char inp[], long long p){
    long long c;
    long long clim;
    int index = 0;
    int len = strlen(inp);
    p += len + 1;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    for (index = len-1; index>=0; index--) {
        clim = inp[index] + 1;
        c = 0;
        for (--p; c<clim;c++) {
            y ^= x;
            x ^= y;
            y ^= c*x;
            x -= p;
            x = x * 17372755581419296689;
            //The multiplicative inverse of 1530089809 mod 2^64.
        }
    }
}
const int rows = 163840;
const int maprows = 524288;

//Store for intermediate input strings, row 0 contains 64 columns with 3-char strings,
//row 1 contain 32 columns with 6-char strings and so forth, the final strings will
//contain one string from each column, in order.
char store[7][rows][512];

//Storage for a hashmap, used for matching n strings with n string in O(n) time.
char map[maprows][512];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int row;
    int col;
    int layer;
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    int colzero;
    //Produce some starting strings.
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++){
        //All column 0 strings begin with 0x08 in order to imitate the hash.
        store[0][row][0] = 8;
        colzero = 1;
        for (col = 0; col < 64; col++){
            store[0][row][col * 8 + colzero] = alpha[a];
            store[0][row][col * 8 + colzero + 1] = alpha[b];
            store[0][row][col * 8 + colzero + 2] = alpha[c];
            store[0][row][col * 8 + colzero + 3] = 0;
            colzero = 0;
        }
        a++;
        if (a >= 52){
            b++;
            a = 0;
            if (b >= 52){
                c++;
                b = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //Layer for layer, column for column, build strings that preserve successively
    //more zero bits. Forward calculated partial hashes are matched with backwards
    //calculated partial hashes.
    for (layer = 1; layer < 7; layer++){
        int slayer = layer - 1;
        int swidth = 1 << (slayer + 3);
        int width = 1 << (layer + 3);
        int slen = 3 << slayer;
        int len = 3 << layer;
        int colnum;
        int layershift=slayer*8;
        for (col = 0,colnum=0; col < 512; col+=width,colnum++){
            printf("Layer: %i, column: %i\n",layer,colnum);
            memset(map, 0, sizeof map);
            int col2 = col + swidth;
            for (row = 0; row < rows; row++){
                hprev(store[slayer][row] + col2, 1 + slen*(1 + colnum * 2));
                x = (x >> layershift) & 255;
                y = (y >> layershift) & 255;
                int index = (x << 3) | (y << 11);
                for (a = 0; a < 8; a++){
                    if (map[index + a][0] == 0){
                        strcpy_s(map[index + a], store[slayer][row] + col2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            int destrow = 0;
            for (row = 0; row < rows && destrow < rows; row++){
                hp(store[slayer][row] + col, !!colnum + slen*(colnum * 2));
                x = (x >> layershift) & 255;
                y = (y >> layershift) & 255;
                int index = (x << 3) | (y << 11);
                for (a = 0; a < 8 && destrow < rows; a++){
                    if (map[index + a][0]){
                        strcpy(store[layer][destrow] + col, store[slayer][row] + col);
                        strcat(store[layer][destrow] + col, map[index + a]);
                        destrow++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    memset(map, 0, sizeof map);
    char temp[1000];
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("hashout.txt");
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++){
        hp(store[6][row], 0);
        sprintf(temp, "%016llx%016llx", x, y);
        myfile << store[6][row] <<" " << temp << "\n";
    }
    myfile << "\n";
    //The final hash set has 96 of 128 output bits set to 0, I could have gone all
    //the way, but this is enough to find a collision via the birthday paradox.
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++){
        hp(store[6][row], 0);
        long long xc = x;
        long long yc = y;
        int pos = (xc >> 45 | ((yc >> 48) & 7)) & (maprows-1);
        while (map[pos][0]!=0){
            hp(map[pos], 0);
            if (x == xc && y == yc){
                myfile << store[6][row] << "\n" << map[pos] << "\n";
                sprintf(temp,"%016llx%016llx", x, y);
                myfile << temp << "\n\n";
            }
            pos = (pos + 1) % maprows;
        }
        strcpy_s(map[pos], store[6][row]);
    }
    myfile.close();
    printf("done");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm actually flattered in an odd sort of way! :D

Comment: Also, for my own personal education, when you say the higher order bits never affect the lower ones, what do you mean?  The higher order bits of the input string, or of the hash state?

Comment: @Mr.Llama In the hash state, the upper bits of x and y will never influence the lower bits, so for instance if you flip on of the middle bits during computation the low part of the hash will still come out right. This lets me start out ignoring everything but the lowest bits of the hash state, then when I have those under complete control I move on to the next layer of bits, and so forth.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Congratulations on winning the robbers challenge!

Answer (score 13):

## [Python, 109 bytes by Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51079/8478)

Note that Martin cracked first, so I'm not sure if this deserves points. On the other hand, I did make a preimage attack rather than a simple collision - a much stronger result. This means that you can give it an arbitrary hash value, and it will construct an input that generates that hash value.

```
M = 2**128

# The hash to crack.
def jenkins(n):
    h = 42
    while n:
        h += n & (M - 1)
        n >>= 128
        h *= 1025
        h ^= h >> 6
        h %= M

    h *= 9
    h ^= h >> 11
    h *= 32769

    return h % M

def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % m

def invxorshift(h, s):
    r = h >> s
    while r:
        h ^= r
        r >>= s
    return h

def moddiv(a, b):
    return (a * modinv(b, M)) % M

def jenkins_crack(h):
    h = moddiv(h, 32769)
    h = invxorshift(h, 11)
    h = moddiv(h, 9)
    h = invxorshift(h, 6)
    h = moddiv(h, 1025)
    h -= 42
    return h
```

And to show that it works:

```
>>> from crack import *
>>> n = 2**128 + 1337
>>> h = jenkins(n)
>>> n2 = jenkins_crack(h)
>>> h2 = jenkins(n2)
>>> n != n2
True
>>> h == h2
True
```

And to give a particular set of numbers that collide:

```
N: 2**128
M: 43617
```

Comment: My initial proposal in the sandbox awarded points for collison, preimage and (slightly oversimplifying things) length extension attacks, but I decided to keep the scoring simple. When I edited those parts out, the fact that every submission can only be cracked once (which is how cops-and-robbers usually works) somehow got lost. Seeing your answer makes me wish I had kept preimage attacks...

Answer (score 9):

## [Python, 109 bytes by Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51079/8478)

```
340282366920938463463374607431768211414
```

and

```
113982837842983129870077688367927159293402923522160868689804433865221255200726
```

both yield

```
132946164914354994014709093261515948032
```

The algorithm splits the input into chunks of 128 bits, and repeatedly modifies the hash (seeded to `42`) with each chunk, before doing some extra hashing at the end. To find a collision, our goal is to find two numbers that yield the same result after running the following pseudo code on each chunk:

```
hash += chunk
hash += (hash << 10)
hash ^= (hash >> 6)
hash %= 2**128
```

Since the hash is taken mod 2<sup>128</sup> we want to look for numbers that shift all the interesting stuff outside of this bit range. But the hash is seeded to `42` so it has some not-so-significant bits set to begin with:

```
000000000000000000000000 ... 000000000000000000101010
```

My idea was to get rid of those bits when adding the first chunk. So let's try 2<sup>128</sup>-42:

```
           000000000000000000000000 ... 000000000000000000101010     hash = 42
           111111111111111111111111 ... 111111111111111111010110     chunk = 2**128 - 42
          1000000000000000000000000 ... 000000000000000000000000     hash += chunk
10000000001000000000000000000000000 ... 000000000000000000000000     hash += hash << 10
10000010001000001000000000000000000 ... 000000000000000000000000     hash ^= hash >> 6
           000001000000000000000000 ... 000000000000000000000000     hash %= 2**128
```

That's fairly simple so let's try to use that as one of the two numbers. (Indeed, the first number of the collision I used is 2<sup>128</sup>-42.

Now how do we find another number with the same result? Well after one iteration the hash isn't `42` any more, but `2**122` as we've just shown. Now by adding a second chunk to our input number, we can run another iteration. We can choose the second chunk by the same argument as this one, i.e. we want 2<sup>128</sup>-2<sup>122</sup>. Then the intermediate result after `hash += chunk` will be identical and we end up with the same result at the end.

So we can compute the two numbers of the collision:

```
>>> 2**128-42
340282366920938463463374607431768211414L
>>> 2**128-42 + ((2**128-2**122)<<128)
113982837842983129870077688367927159293402923522160868689804433865221255200726L
```

We can easily generate many more collisions like this.

Comment: I was also cracking this - almost done. Is this a fastest gun in the west contest or can I still get points for posting it?

Comment: @orlp Normally only the first robber gets a point. Otherwise, people could just generate millions of additional cracks once the first crack has been posted.

Comment: Lame =/ Think I'll stop doing this challenge then. I don't enjoy racing against others - I just want to puzzle. Can't there be some time window for cracks after the first, with only 1 crack per person?

Comment: @orlp The original version in the sandbox had three different methods of cracking a cop, and all three could be posted independently. I guess that's an interesting model to investigate at some point. But so far in previous CnRs allowing multiple cracks would always have broken the challenge more than it would have improved it.

Comment: See my answer for a preimage attack, rather than a collision :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Mathematica, 89 bytes by LegionMammal978](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51080/8478)

```
0
```

and

```
16
```

Both yield `0`.

The principle of this cop is to evolve a "random" binary 1-D cellular automaton from a "random" initial condition for a "random" number of steps, and then interpret the first 128 cells of the result as an integer.

The problem is that the rule is determined simply by `Mod[#^2,256]`, such that any multiple of 16 gives rule `0`, which is the trivial rule where all cells are always zero. If the input is not divisible by 99 then we will evolve at least 1 step, so the output is always zero. So any two multiples that aren't multiples of 99 definitely collide. However, input `0` *also* gives 0 (despite never using the rule), because the initial condition is just the binary representation of the input (which is all zeroes in this case).

As an aside, we can find other collisions that are completely independent of the rule. As noted above, any multiple of 99 means that the cellular automaton isn't evolved at all, so the result is simply the first (most significant) 128 bits of the initial condition... which is itself just the input number. So if we take two multiples that don't differ in the first 128 bits (padded to the right with zeroes), we also get a collision. The simplest example of this is `M = 99`, `N = 99*2 = 198`.

Answer (score 8):

## [J, 39 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51083/21487)

The first number is:

```
10000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000
```

That is, `10000000` repeated 64 times. The second number  is that plus one, i.e.

```
10000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000001
```

Both yield

```
322124197561777885386414076216564234267
```

### Explanation

Let's start with `x := H 10000000 = 146018215378200688979555343618839610915`, and `y := 2^128`. Rather than finding `a, b` such that `a == b mod y`, we'll look for `a, b` such that `x^a == x^b mod y`, making use of the power towers in the algorithm.

But there must be some `k` such that `x^k == 1 mod y`, since `x, y` are coprime, and for that `k` we must have `a == b mod k`. So we can find the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) of 1 mod `y`, and for the first step we get

```
x ^ (k = 85070591730234615865843651857942052864) == 1 mod 2^128
```

So now we want to find two numbers `a, b` such that `a == b mod k`. To do this, we set `y` to be `k` and try to find `a, b` such that `x^a == x^b mod y` again. Using the same logic, we take the discrete logarithm again and get

```
x ^ (k = 21267647932558653966460912964485513216) == 1 mod 85070591730234615865843651857942052864
```

We repeat this until we get to a small `y`, at which point it is trivial to find two numbers which hash to the same thing modulo `y`. After 63 iterations `y = 4`, at which point basically any two numbers work.

Here's the Mathematica code to generate the discrete log chain:

```
k = 0; x = 146018215378200688979555343618839610915; y = 2^128; While[y > 10, y = MultiplicativeOrder[x, y]; k++; Print[k, " ", y]];
```

This gives the [following output](http://pastebin.com/jhFa2dCF).

Comment: The slightly shorter version is that if the first few hundreds of digits are the same it is improbable that the rest of the input matter in any way at all. Actually doing maths to break this is overkill.

Comment: @eBusiness That's true. It turned out that it didn't matter much here, but initially I was worried about going over the `2^(2^30)` limit, hence the check.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that it might be impossible to fabricate a string where anything beyond the 512th digit matters. You managed to produce the worst-case scenario. Easiest crack must be to take advantage of internal leading zeroes: "100000001" "1000000001".

Answer (score 7):

### [Pyth, 8 bytes by FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51074/21487)

```
99999999999999999999999999
```

and

```
99999999999999999999999998
```

Floating point precision isn't big enough for this.

Comment: I'm actually getting different results for this, but I do believe that this strategy would work anyway, so I'll mark it as cracked. Fast work :P

Comment: Hmm weird. I get `437409784163148` for both. I wonder why there's a difference...

Comment: You're probably using python 3.5 right? I haven't updated yet, still on 3.4 maybe that's it?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'm using the online interpreter, actually...

Comment: Actually yeah I get `437409784163148` and `37409784163148` so I guess it's just lost the last digit for some reason, but 99...997 gives the same answer as 999...98.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman There, I added more 9s. How's that? :P

Comment: Yep that's the same. Are you sure you aren't Randall's cat? :P

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam, 44 bytes, <s>user</s> jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51103/21487)

The numbers are too big to post, so here they are on Pastebin: [num 1](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CT25Av3y), [num 2](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uZinA136).

The first number is `600^2 = 360000` ones. The second number is the same, except for the following changes:

```
Positions to change to "2": 605, 1811, 3001, 6603
Positions to change to "4": 1805, 3003, 57348, 208895
Positions to change to "5": 602, 1201, 2405, 3004
Positions to change to "6": 1203, 1802
Positions to change to "7": 12, 609, 5401, 7200
Positions to change to "8": 1, 2, 4, 6, 600, 1200, 1808, 2400, 3600, 4803
```

Both hash to `271088937720654725553339294593617693056`.

### Explanation

Let's take a look at the first half of the code:

```
lW%                e#  Read input number as string, and reverse
600/               e#  Split every 600 digits, forming a 2D array
_z                 e#  Duplicate and zip, swapping rows and columns
{           }%     e#  For both arrays...
 JfbDb             e#  Find sum of S[i][j]*13^i*19^j, where S are the character values
                   e#  and the indices are from right to left, starting at 0.
      GK#          e#  Take modulo 16^20

         ...  ...  e#  (Rest of code irrelevant)
```

So if we can find two input numbers so that the sums of `S[i][j]*13^i*19^j` are the same modulo `16^20` for both the initial 600-wide array and the zipped array, then we're done.

To make things a little easier, we'll consider only `600^2 = 360000`-digit input numbers, so that the 600-wide array is just a 600 by 600 square of digits. This makes things easier to visualise, and is valid since `10^360000 ~ 2^(2^20.19) < 2^(2^30)`. To simplify things even further, we'll only consider such input strings whose digit square is symmetric along the main diagonal, so that the original array and the zipped array are the same. This also allows us to ignore the initial string reversal and the right-to-left index numbering, which cancel each other out.

To start us off, we can take the first number to be `360000` ones. To get the second number, we want to modify this by changing some of the digits so that the sums are the same modulo `16^20`, while preserving the digit square's symmetry. We accomplish this by finding a list of triples `(i, j, k)` so that

```
sum of k*(13^i 19^j + 19^i 13^j) == 0 mod 16^20
```

where `1 <= k <= 8` is the amount to increase the digit 1 by (i.e. changing to a digit from 2 to 9 – we could have included 0 but we didn't need it) and `0 <= i < j < 600` are index pairs.

Once we have the `(i, j, k)` triplets, we change the digits at `(i, j)` and `(j, i)` to `1+k` to get the second number. The triplets were found using a greedy backtracking algorithm, and for the second number above the digit square looks like:

```
188181811111711 ...
815112111711111 ...
851611111111111 ...
116114118112111 ...
811115111111111 ...
121451111111111 ...
811111111111111 ...
111111111111111 ...
111811111111111 ...
171111111111111 ...
111111111111111 ...
111211111111111 ...
711111111111111 ...
111111111111111 ...
111111111111111 ...

............... .
...............  .
...............   .
```

For example, `(i, j, k) = (0, 1, 7)` corresponds to changing the digits `(0, 1)` (position `600*0 + 1 = 1`) and `(1, 0)` (position `600*1 + 0 = 600`) to `1 + 7 = 8`.

---

Here's the backtracker in Python 3, although closer inspection revealed that we were pretty lucky, as no backtracking actually happened:

```py
n = 16**20
L = [(k *(pow(13,i,n)*pow(19,j,n) + pow(19,i,n)*pow(13,j,n)) % n, i, j, k)
     for i in range(600) for j in range(600) for k in range(1, 9) if i < j]

L.sort(reverse=True)
stack = [(n, 0, [])]

while stack:
    k, index, result = stack.pop()

    if k == 0:
        print(result)
        break

    if index == len(L):
        continue

    stack.append((k, index+1, result)) # Don't include triplet

    if L[index][0] <= k:
        stack.append((k - L[index][0], index+1, result + [L[index][1:]])) # Include
```

For a bonus, [here's](http://ideone.com/UuC6Ur) a not-so-efficient port of the hash in Python 3. It was useless.

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP 4.1, 66 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51118/7773) by [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel)

```
$ A=0111129112911291111111111111111111111111 php hash.php 2> /dev/null ; echo
0100038003800381129111111111111111111111
$ A=0111129112911291129111111111111111111111 php hash.php 2> /dev/null ; echo
0100038003800381129111111111111111111111
$ cat hash.php 
<? $a = getenv("A"); for($l=strlen($b.=$a*1);$i<40;$o.=+$b[+$i]^"$a"/$a,$i++);echo$o;
```

Found using simple iterated hashing, starting from 1:

```
$ i=1; while true; do i=$(A=$i php hash.php  2> /dev/null); echo $i; done | head -n 10
0111111111111111111111111111111111111111
0100000000000001129111111111111111111111
0111129111111111111111111111111111111111
0100038000000001129111111111111111111111
0111129112911111111111111111111111111111
0100038003800001129111111111111111111111
0111129112911291111111111111111111111111
0100038003800381129111111111111111111111
0111129112911291129111111111111111111111
0100038003800381129111111111111111111111
```

Comment: Yup, that one is cracked. How long did it took to reach there?

Comment: The second try. The first try was looking the values of the first 100 hashes, second try was making the hash chains (i.e. `hash(hash(hash(...(hash(1)...)))`). The first chain converged into a loop almost instantly. I didn't even need to bring up my multithreaded hash cracker.

Comment: Translation: pretty weak hash?

Comment: Yes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3 (216) by Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51126/30688)

My messages are

```
5012053369354645637214643587103597313576086380250249302980438772005248488380915054746146050001036696049972235875591571028140916001206596142280971107479334216535925703480968283657357930602076844092875640359192729378384507238123245417656548512647301639542279794868512420586823155070914644206130805893968511673770843170450832829657206145931885656157628306896903719624729809643572222159364893644113710867223921580178741177106141068298067479650611992859787419779579962211254029169589775046869542029842374359998053713002047081002506346875804341770199884355810931652447801492691887376948615365487982834690942054717077615539311699691010938426302886867891090301248321702485904291177813145565144089044261424329155436660979948932491709511914065619715728353376578192548334780893602675684085757434059540582004872746967999949306946618036846307799677491651967418565531672392468089533111553281620101129322575737949904022139471688252420467041529301533363008476437812216585923822571793353317799365005036029476865
5012053369354645637214643587103103086948976188724715498910865650846170784131001427390927276355140411160919276493388206817700368694224128444524223814513348177926532982330730066315320819293979046126543806115318009892783577432467861426768883700930779409885418980853424256180864755881414774514084197887594253752179391098292488771920695965135791582218083012144604515253506370334133858904659263953147111654656123599460222236152128559750436960308887683690915261431659087040402402092795259541564130228515353133867041828417398395559815392177084002004583988047406317670433664624642858480970640416500369367395538257341309676777745698712896295462462064271676447460293684100001583256400774270688958051470568447233589146620275159126426142305307007744396679875427883384557759778766330566230012377845843842097372663092379922300568052486301863154557664156185573021849420011058607321977550938866119133331529852821217331665195832442542012455132139770813510559894254061471149750738447764616026512400623344132554752
```

I used this Python 2 code to generate them:

```
a,b = 14460445391122031029,16815296360833931837 #http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php
pr = ~-a * ~-b

m0 = reduce(long.__or__, [long(b) << 26*i for i,b in enumerate(bin(pr)[2:])])
m1 = 1 << 26*i-1
m0 |= m1

#print m0, m1
print f(m0), f(m1)
```

The big modulus was a product of two primes `a` and `b`. I guess the hope was that it would be NP-impossible for us to factor the semiprime, but I guess 128 bits is too small as some webpage gave me the answer right away.

The multiplicative group modulo `ab` will have order *(a - 1)(b - 1)* which means if we raise any number to that power it will have to result in 0 or (usually) 1. So I put 1 bits in places that resulted in *2<sup>(a-1)(b-1)</sup>* being multiplied into the hash. Then the other message is basically 0, but I set one other bit in each number to make the lengths the same.

I think it would have been more annoying were the hash squared on every bit, rather than only after using all the primes. Then it wouldn't have been so simple to build arbitrary exponents for them.

Comment: Nice work :) Yeah the vulnerability I had in mind was basically that the semiprime is visible in the code, and I realised Mathematica could factor it instantly.

Comment: +1 Your code is hard to read, but otherwise a nice and instructive crack.

Answer (score 5):

## [C, 128 bytes - by: squeamish ossifrage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51190/101)

The following two strings both hash to all zeroes:

```
dddl|lddH4|@dhxdxXdh0TXPdhhdx(dTxtlpdd@4Lhd|hdDpdhDdXLdXP4(PdddL|ldXdD(lddX4|0hddp4|ddP4Lxdp0dP@dhpTxPdhXdXxdhHDxHdllLttdhPT8pd(pT8Pdd0TL8dlLLTtddPtl8dP@DPPdhhDxhd804(pdh0Txpd@DDpLdhL4xtdXXdHXdd04lXht40dlddh4|@ddPTLXdhhDXHhtPH40dh0t8pd(pt80dhPtX0dhLtXtdhLT8thlLplTdhpt80dh0txpdhHDX(hdX8txdhhdxHdp|d@tdhlTx4dlptdxdh0T8PdT@t|Hdd@tL(ht(8DhdhHD8(hpHHP8dhLtXtdX8dhxdhpt8Pd@(D@Hdd@tLhdtxTLPdd0tlxhhL8X|dd8t|0dT04|Xddxt|phxxxhhdhpt8PhhxX8hdhlTX4dd4l||dd@TLHdXlTHtdhHd8hdX0THPdh(D8(d8xdh8dhp4xPd0HDp(dhl4xTdxlthtdhlTx4d8lT(TdhhdXHdphdP(dhp4x0d0Xd0XddTl||d88DH8dhhdxhdx|tHDdhLT8Thll0lTddPTlXdxXd(xdd0Tlxdhp480dhp4x0dd|LltdhPt80dtll|dddPTlXdxXd(xdd0Tlxdhp480dhp4x0dd|LltdhPt80dtll|dddP4Lxd|ptT8dhddxldH|4xDdhp4x0dDdl|LdhtD8|hhHx88ddpTL8hhphx@dhtd8|dphDP(dh0tx0hhDHx4dhpt8Pd@(D@HddLLLDhh|xxldhl4xTdhL4x4dhPt8Pd(HDx(dh(D8Hd4PT|8ddH4|@hh4H8ddhxd8XdDP4lxdhHd8hdl04d8ddXT|phdh8Thdd@TlHdhXdxxdllL44dD@4lHdhxdxXhd8XtxddLlLddT@T|(dhxdXXd|P44Xdhpt8pdlHDT0dhL4Xtd@ldpDdddl|LdXP4h0dhltXtdX8d(Xdh|tXdhhLXX|dhxd8XdP@D0PdhXDxXhtpHtPdd84|pddtl||dh(dx(d88Dh8ddx4|PhtT0DLdd@tL(hdX8Txdhp480d08d08dlll44d4dLLldhTdX|hh8Xxhdh048pd08d08ddPtL8d4H4l@dhhdxHd|pt4Xddp4lXhp(hPxdh|48DdxhDh(ddLlldd8XdH8dddl|LdLHDT0dhpt8pdlHDT0dh(d8hdTHtl@ddptl8dt84LPdh8dxxdlptD8dd04lxhhH8XxddDl|ldP|D@4ddTl||d|ptT8dh(dXhhd8X48dhPtXpd(8DxXdh@TX@dDP4L8dhpTX0d4@4|hdhHdxHdX8DHxdhPT8PhllplTdh0TXPhlXHLXddp4lXhtHXD(dhP4X0htH8dhdhLTx4hpxHPHdhhd8(dX8DHxdhpt80hhdHxTdlll44d@Hd@(dhhDxhdh0t8Pddh4|@ddh4|@dhptx0dpPD0@ddPtlxdhPT8pdhhdX(htTpDLdd@4L(dLHDtpdhxd8xdt84lPdlpTdxdDPTLXddLLLDdxlThtdlhd4PdXLTh4ddptLxd|@44(dhhd8HdtDLLlddxt|pd|hDd0ddPtLXhl@H|pdhDD8ld8dDhLdhXDXxdDxT|PdhHD8hdp8dpxdhp480d@XD@xddpTLXdHhD8(ddllLDdD|LL4dhpt80d@LdPDdh|4xDdP8dpXddLllddl8d4@dhptXpdd(4|@dhltx4d0Dd@LdhptxphdPHdpdhl4xTdxlthtdhHD8HdTdllldhLtX4dXP4(PdhLTxTd4X4LpddlllDdlpTD8dllltTdL(dtPdhDDxLdhLTx4dhptx0d|0T4Xdhl4xTdHL4XtdhpTXpdLp4dxddHt|@dHL484dhHDXHdHLtxtdhDdXldxL4H4dh|TxDhh8xX(dhLt8td8Lt(TdhHDx(d4DlLlddXT|PdHHD8(dlll44dlP4dxdd@tL(dL@4dhdd0tLxd4X4l0dhhdxhdDlLldddLLlddD04l8ddPtlxd(hd8hdd(T|@hdDp4|ddP4Lxdp0dP@dhptXpd(p4X0dhhd8(d8pT(0dh8d8Xhd(XT(dhddxLd@XD@8dd@tlhd@ld0ddhTD8|hhPH8@ddtl||dH0Tx0ddLlLddhp480dhHdxhd4lL|DdhXD8xdhhDX(dh048pd4Ll|ddddl|LdXP4h0dlll4thhdhxtddP4LXdhXdxXdhpTX0hdXXtxddlLLddx0Th0ddTl||hlhhlHdd|Ll4dHDdXldhhDX(hpxh0HdhDDXLdXDDhLdlhDTpht8Xdxdhpt8phhHXX8dd(t|@dHl4xtddp4LXhxhXH8dhDDxldDXt|PdhTDX|d|0ttxdhdDXLdDLLLddd84|PdT84LpdlhDTphl8hlxdhXD8xdHpt8Pdlhd40ddHT|@dhxdX8dhlT84dh|T8dhlXHLxdhxDxXdT4lL|dlllttd@xd@xdhhDXHhtXXD8dh(d8(d4p4|8dd04lxdxPThpdhHD8Hhdhx4hdhl4xthl|pLDdhltX4dhP4XPdd0Tlxdl@tDhddP4lXd0xD0xdhHD8Hd@8D@xdh0T8Pd0XDpxddPtl8dP@DPPdhhDxhd804(pdd04L8hpxHphdhDdxLdppD0@dd@tl(d88dHXdh0txpdXhDhHdd@Tlhdx8DHXdh0tXPdxxdH8dhPT8Pd484LPdlhD4pdxxdHxdd|Lltdhptx0dhlTx4hp8HPhdhPt8pdt4lL|ddtl||dH0Tx0dhxd8xhl@H|pddLllDhldP||dhdD8ldXLTHTdlhDTpddllLddd04lxhhH8Xxdh|48DdP8d0XddLLldd|@44hdhhd8hd4x4L0dhltXthh4H8Ddh4DX|dD@Tlhdh0tXpd8|T(ddhtDX|dlhdTPdd@tLhdThTl@dh8D8xdT(TL@dd@Tl(d8Hd(hdhXdxxhtHXdhdd0tl8d|HDDPdd8T|PdH04xPdd@Tl(d|@4t(dd(4|@dHp4xpdhpt80dh0txpdhp48phdXxTxdhhDXHhtPH40dh0t8pd(pt80dd8T|pdlxdt@dhp48PdD0TLXdh0t8Pd|lldTdh|t8DhphHp8

ddTl||d4|L|4dhptX0d4dllLddxT|pdxXdH8dlhDtPhlpH|@dd|Lltdhptx0dhlTx4hp8HPhdhPt8pdt4lL|ddtl||dH0Tx0ddLLLDd8tdH|dhDD8LdtxtLpdhxD8Xhd8xtxdhPt8Pd(8DX8dhddxLd0xd08dd0Tlxdxdd(Lddh4|@dXpt(Pdh048pd0xd0xdhhDX(d8p4Hpdh0480d(8DX8dhL4x4d4PT|XddPTLXdPDd@Ldddl|ld(P4X0ddDL|lht88DXdhPtxpd((Dx(dh0tx0dxXd(8dhpT8Pd0xD0XdlhD4pdT0T|8dh04XPht0H40dlhDtpdpHDP(dhlTXtdPHdpHdhXDxXhpPH0pddDl|lhltp|Ldh04x0dtXTL0ddLLLDdLhdtpdhL4xtdHDdXLddxt|0d4X4l0dh(Dxhdx04h0ddllLDd0PD0@dhXDxxhdx848dhDDxldpXDpXdhPt8pdhltxTdd04lxhhH8Xxdh|48DdP8d0XddLLldd|@44hdhhd8hd4x4L0dhltXthh4H8Ddh4DX|dD@Tlhdh0tXpd8|T(ddhtDX|dlhdTPdhlTXtdTX4L0dd@Tlhhh8xXHdhPt80d|XdD@dhp4xphd4Ptldd|LL4dL|ltDdhPTx0d80T(pdhpt8pd|pTtXdhpTX0hhth8Ddhxd8xdphdP(dh8D88dp(DPhdhHD8(htxXdXdh8dXXdXpTH0ddx4|PdpXDPxdhXDXXdxxdhXdhlt8Td@xD@8dhP4XPdhltX4dd@tlHdhXDxxdhPtXPd(8Dxxdh0t8PhdpHd0dh(D8HdX(D(Hdd@tLhht|@4Tdd@4lHdttll|dd0tlXhh|xxldd@TLHdlHdTPdd|LL4dt@T|hddx4|PdlHdtPddTl||d88DH8dlhdTpd40t|xddht|@dpPDP@dhHDxHhxthHDdhddxldxtDH|dhltx4d8Dd(ldd|LLthp0H0Pdhl4x4d|0T4Xdd|ll4dt8tLPdd@4lhd|0TTXddPtLXd(8d8xdhPTxPdHxd8xdhHDX(ddLllddhp48Pd0@d0PdhptxpdX(DhHdd0TlXhtPHTPddh4|@dTDlLldhDDxLhp(hPxdhdD8ldXLTHTddPtLXdTh4L@dhLtxTdlpTd8dhPtXpdhLtX4ddPTlXdxxdhXdhhd8(d404|8dhTd8|dhL4Xtddp4l8d4X4LpdhL4Xtd@ldpDdddl|LdXP4h0dhpTX0htXxDxdhpt8pddLlLddhp4XPhp0H00dh4Dx|dlp4D8dhPtxpd((Dx(dh0tx0dxXd(8dhDDxlhlL0ltdhhDxHd@|d0TdhHdxhdL0tD8dhhD8hhl|pLdddxt|pd|hDd0ddPtLXhl@H|pdhxDXxd8DdhldlhdtphpphppdhpT8PdH8dxXdlhd40dtXtlPdhTd8|dXlthtdhTDX|dx|4HDddxT|pdHDd8ldhL4X4dhP4XpdhtDx|ddXt|Pdh|T8DdHhdxhddLLLDhlxHl8dh0tXPd|(ddPddDL|LdHhdxhdhp4x0dl8dT@ddXT|phdh8Thdh(DXhd0HDP(dddl|lhd(xT(dhXdXxdTxtl0dd|lLtd8|4hddd4l||dXLTh4dd04lxdP8DP8ddxT|0dXXdh8ddP4lxd0@DpPdh8dXxddp4lxdhLt8tdHTdx|dh4Dx|dxLTHtdhhd8hd@DDpldd04LXdXlT(tdhXdXxdhPT8pdh(DXHdP@dp0ddP4LXdXpThPdllL4td((D8(dh0tXpd|(ddpdh(DxhhdL@DDdhHDx(dxL4(tdhLtXtdl@4dHdhxd8xdTh4L@dhXDXXhhdH8Tdd8T|PdH04xPdlllT4hllpLtdhhDXHhxxXhhdhXDxXdPDd@Ldd0TlXdHLtX4ddDL|ldXLT(4dhPtXPdXXd(8dhpt8phdH8thddxT|pd(ptXpddP4LxdLXDT@dhpT80dLptDxddxt|pdP@Dp0dhptx0d|0T4XdlpTdxdxpt(PdhHD8(d4TlL|dhHDx(d@hD@(dd@tl(d88dHXdh(Dx(d4pT|xddPtl8dP@DPPdhhDxhd804(pdhHD8Hhdhx4hddP4lxhdhXt(dhxdX8dp@DppdlllT4dP0dp@dddl|ldH8DXXdllLT4dPXdp8dd@tLHdlPTd8ddtL||d8PtHpddHt|@hd|@d4dh(dX(hdhXT(dhpT80hdHX4(dlpTdxdtDlLlddxT|pd(ptXpddP4LxdLXDT@dhpT80dLptDxddxt|pdP@Dp0dhptx0d|0T4XdlpTdxdxpt(PdhHD8(d4TlL|dhHDx(d@hD@(dddL|lhtph40dhpTxPdlp4dXdhDDxldpxD08dh(dX(dHlTxTdd|ll4d40t|Xdh0480ht@hT@dhptXphdHxT(dh(D8Hd4PT|8dhpt8pd88dhXddDl|LhxdHHtddPtlXd|pt4Xdd0Tl8d0(D0hdhhd8hdppd0@ddPTlXd8P4hpdhlTx4d8dDhLdd@TLhhllplTddXT|0dH|4XDdh|4xDht8XD8ddptl8dH8d88dd|LLTdh(DXhddHt|@hpXhp(dhdDxLdDhT|@dhP4X0dXhDHhdh0T8Pd((dxhdhhDx(hdx8Txddp4LXd8xDH8dhPTXpdlPtD8dh(DxHd@8D@Xdhl48Td00Dp@dhLT8Tdp(d0(dhhd8(d404|8dhhdx(dx0T(pdd|lL4ddXt|Pdd0TlXhxdH(4ddllLDhhLXX|dhXDx8hl8hLxdhpT80dLPtDXdhptX0dPXd0XddP4lxd0@DpPdlptd8dl(dTPdhxDx8d(ptX0dhpT80htxxdXdhhDxhdXltHtddh4|@d@|dPTdhdDXLhpph0Pdhp48Pdt4lL|dh04xpdLpTD8dd@4lhdl8dt@ddhT|@dPxDp8dd04lXd40t|xdd0TLxdTdlLLddpTLXd|pTT8dd04lxhhH8XxdhddxlhddPT|dd04LXdlhd4pdh8d8xhh|8XLdhxd8xd(8d8xdhp48pd(8DX8dhhDXHd4dllLddx4|0d8PTH0ddPtlxd|P44XdlpTdxd(XDXXddpTlxdHltX4dhLTxtd|HDD0
```

The hash function is built so that higher order bits never influence lower order bits, therefore I can generate a collection of strings where all of the `x` lower order bits are zero, then I can try concatenated combinations of these strings to find some where more of the lower bits are zero etc. I'm pretty sure that there are more ways of breaking this, and also ways that produce significantly shorter strings, but this way I avoided doing a lot of maths.

Comment: Awesome! They both hash to `0x0000000a0000000a0000000a0000000a` on my system, but that's still pretty amazing. (`echo -ne '\x0a' |./hash` also gives the same result.)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You have a rouge newline after each of the strings, without that it is plain zeroes.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3, 118 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51144/41288)

```
int(H("9"+"0"*400))
```

and

```
int(H("9"+"0"*4000))
```

(that is: 9E400 and 9E4000)

Both produce

```
83909358607540647658718900164058931893
```

Digging somewhat deeper, it seems that any integer followed by k repeated digits such that k > 128 and (k%4 == 0) will return the same hash. For example, `H("1"+"1"*32*4)` and `H("1"+"1"*33*4)` are both `13493430891393332689861502800964084413`. Hmmm, 128...

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2, 161 bytes, by Puzzled](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51193/25180)

```
340282366920938463463374607431768211456 (decimal)
100000000000000000000000000000000 (hexadecimal)
```

and

```
340282366920938468780317283222139437056 (decimal)
100000000000001203B66F94300000000 (hexadecimal)
```

Both have the output:

```
83F172CC3D050D131F64FD04B8181DC2
```

The numbers are 2^128 and 2^128 + (3*5*7*11*13*17)^2*19*2^32.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java, 299 bytes by SuperJedi224](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51087/8478)

[Pastebin for `M`.](http://pastebin.com/JDeSB2ua) In binary, `M` has 65535 `1`s, followed by 2 `0`s.

[Pastebin for `N`.](http://pastebin.com/u14drwgf) In binary, `N` has 21845 `1`s, followed by 174766 `0`s.

Both yield `0`.

Note that the basis of the algorithm is `i.bitCount()*i.bitLength()+1` and ultimately, we take the result to the power of `i` and take it mod 2<sup>128</sup>. So the idea was just to find two `i` that are divisible by four, but where the first expression gives 2<sup>32</sup>. That was easily done by factoring 2<sup>32</sup>-1 and picking two factors for the count of 1s and total bit width of the number.

**Edit:** Actually, there's a bit more to why `M` yields zero, but we can easily find more numbers that yield zero because of my explanation by using other factors of 2<sup>32</sup>-1 such that there are at least 64 zeroes at the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [C, 134 bytes (by Barteks2x)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51094/11006)

```
10
```

and

```
20
```

both hash to

```
0xa609779942cb9ef1
```

because the algorithm only hashes the last digit!

Comment: That was a stupid mistake...

Answer (score 3):

### [C, 87 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51146/7773)

```
$ echo B075343F9832CD60 | ./hash6_ ; echo
fc2e9f02bd284bd1
$ echo 5914BD1B71164C77 | ./hash6_ ; echo
fc2e9f02bd284bd1
```

Found using my collision bruteforcer.

Comment: Maybe it's because of only being 64-bit.

Comment: Well done :-)  How long did it take?

Comment: About 7 minutes of running the program. Now started again with measurements.

Comment: Found another collision: `473E0B6ED5AF2B92 7EC2BC9B5E9F5645 -> 0000000000000000 0EAC34C8A9F94389` after 3525078917 hash function calls and `real 14m24.970s user 48m42.410s` time.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2, 115 bytes, by squeamish ossifrage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51313/25180)

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

and

```
2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The hash value had nothing to do with the order of blocks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2.x, 139 bytes by Puzzled](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51177/36885)

`H(2)`

and

`H(128)`

both return

`16645614427504350476847004633262883518`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C++, 239 bytes by SpelingMistake](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51175/41288)

Using the provided "main" program, the following two inputs produce the same hash:

```
echo -n "dog" | ./h
481c27f26cba06cf
```

and

```
echo -n "fog" | ./h
481c27f26cba06cf
```

The *first 8 bytes of input are never processed*, due to this bug in the code:

```
 for(I i=n;--i;) // and then we use q[i] for this iteration
```

because `--i` evaluates to false when `i==1`, `q[0]` (the first 8 bytes: `I` is an `int64`). Replacing the loop condition with `for(I i=n;i--;)` would have fixed this.

Comment: Looks like the first 8 bytes of input are just ignored.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the code; the fix is going suffix instead of prefix.

Comment: There are non-bug collisions as well (see comments to the original question).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby, 90 Bytes, by MegaTom](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51237/25180)

```
4271974071841820164790043412339104229205409044713305539894083215644439451561281100045924173873152
```

and

```
23495857395130010906345238767865073260629749745923180469417457686044416983587046050252582956302336
```

which are 2 and 11 followed by 40 zero bytes. So they both have 41 bytes. The hash value is added by the input length for each byte, and then it is reversed in decimal. A input length ending with `1` can make sure the hash value will end with a `0` pretty quickly. Then reversing it reduces the length of the hash value by 1.

Both have the hash value `259`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# - 393 bytes - by: Logan Dam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51265/101)

`70776e65642062792031333337206861786f72` and `70776e65642062792031333337206861786f7200` both hash to `18E1C8E645F1BBD1`.

Comment: Cool! Could you explain how you cracked it? And maybe the "faulty padding"?

Comment: @LoganDam It is all that code that switch around the input, you end up processing a multiple of 8 characters, and if the input length isn't a multiple of 8, you substitute zeroes. If I add in some zeroes in the right place they simply take the place of the padding, which was zeroes in the first place.