# Hashers and Crashers (Cops)

Tags: cops-and-robbers, hashing

*This is the cops thread of this cops and robbers challenge. The robbers thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264164/hashers-and-crashers-robbers).*

[Related, but hashes numbers instead of strings and uses a different scoring system.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51068/117478)

### Definitions

A hash collision is when two different strings produce the same hash.

### Summary

In this challenge, the cops will make a hash function, with a collision they know of. Then, the robbers will try to crack it by finding a hash collision in the cop's hash algorithm. To crack an answer, the hash collision the robber finds does not have to be the intended solution.

If a cop submission is not cracked for 7 days, it is safe, so mark it as such and reveal the intended crack and the score.
 If a cop submission is cracked, mark it as such and edit in a link to the crack.

### Rules

- Cryptographic functions are allowed only if you know a collision in them. If it is a famous and secure hash algorithm like SHA-256, you must post the hashes of each string in a different, specified hash algorithm (ideally also in a secure hash algorithm), like Keccak-512.

### Format

A cop answer has to **contain the language and the source code**.

### Scoring

The score of a safe cop answer is **the sum of the number of bytes of the two strings with the hash collision, with the *lower* score being better**.

### The winner

With robbers and cops being ranked separately, the winner is the person with the best scoring answer.

### Example

Cop:

> #### Python
>
> ```
> from hashlib import*
> def singlecharhash(x):
>   a = blake2b(digest_size=1)
>   a.update(x)
>   return a.hexdigest()
> ```

Robber:

> #### 4 Points, Cracks cop's answer
>
> `¯` and `É`, both 2 bytes.

### Pinboard

I am thinking of changing the scoring system to make it the minimum of the two strings. Any thoughts?

Comment: Note your example submission is invalid since [using cryptography in a cops and robbers challenge is a standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19323/91213)

Comment: Also `É` is not one byte in utf-8. if you use a different encoding you need to state which one

Comment: @mousetail I have rectified both.

Comment: @mousetail OP specifically overrides that loophole for this challenge. If you can find a collision in Blake 2B, you can use it (good luck with that tho)

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms That was edited in after my comment

Comment: Finding a collision is a lot easier than finding a collision for a specific hash.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms mousetail is correct about me editing it in.

Comment: @mousetail what do you mean by that?

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @mousetail Ok. People could mitigate this by having longer or variable hash length.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer You need exactly double the hash length to compensate

Comment: @mousetail you can also use variable hash length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147892/discussion-between-the-empty-string-photographer-and-mousetail).

Comment: A variable length still has some average entropy, and to crack it you need only to brute force half that entropy

Comment: Note that `return STRING2 if sha256(x) == STRING1 else return sha256(x)` would have `sha256^-1(STRING1)` and `sha256^-1(STRING2)` as a collision, but all other collisions would imply a collision in SHA256 (which obviously isn't feasible for a robber to find)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264187/73054)

```py
import hmac

def my_hash(x):
    assert type(x) == bytes
    return hmac.digest(x, b'good luck', 'sha256')
```

Function takes bytes. There are no typing/Python tricks here, it's a pure crypto challenge.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264187/73054). Possibly not what you intended...