# Hashers and Crashers (Robbers)

Tags: cops-and-robbers, hashing

*This is the robbers thread of this cops and robbers challenge. The cops thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264161/hashers-and-crashers-cops)*.

[Related, but hashes numbers instead of strings and uses a different scoring system.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51068/117478)

### Definitions

A hash collision is when two different strings produce the same hash.

### Summary

In this challenge, the cops will make a hash function, with a collision they know of. Then, the robbers will try to crack it by finding a hash collision in the cop's hash algorithm. To crack an answer, the hash collision the robber finds does not have to be the intended solution.

If a cop submission is not cracked for 7 days, it is safe, so mark it as such and reveal the intended crack and the score.
 If a cop submission is cracked, mark it as such and edit in a link to the crack.

### Format

A robber answer has to contain **the hash collision, a link to the cracked answer, and the score**.

### Scoring

The score of a robber answer is **the sum of the number of bytes of the two strings with the hash collision, with the *higher* score being better**.

### The winner

With robbers and cops being ranked separately, the winner is the person with the best scoring answer.

### Example

Cop:

> #### Python
>
> ```
> from hashlib import*
> def singlecharhash(x):
>   a = blake2b(digest_size=1)
>   a.update(x)
>   return a.hexdigest()
> ```

Robber:

> #### 4 Points, Cracks cop's answer
>
> `¯` and `É`, both 2 bytes.

### Pinboard

I am thinking of changing the scoring system to make it the minimum of the two strings. Any thoughts?

Comment: What if cracker can construct collision of extremely long one?

Comment: @l4m2 then it’s totally fine.

Comment: It gives infinite score and can't compare

Comment: @l4m2 it’s a trade off. Post a crack with a short char length immediately or spend some time and then post a crack with a longer char length.

Comment: There's case where generating a longer one is easier

Comment: @l4m2 then that’s ok. The cops should try to be competitive.

Answer (score 5):

## [Cracks Sisyphus's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264180/73054), 1 byte

`b''` and `b'\x00'`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RCsIwDEXf@xXxqSsMmRNFhP2JIN0W1zHXljaD9etrV1AQzVM4uSeJDaSMPl6si3GcrXEEapYdYz0@YA53Jb0qVnFlkEp6jylAwWJi0DTQBkKfZw5pcTrL@34c0FOxltDywZgenks38RK4V7I@nbmIE4YDJJ1zlto6t7e1qjizbtRUvC9vOSF@Yf2BedOugQz/2dub32Z8AQ)

I'm not sure if this is the intended solution but it's definitely the simplest.

As @gsitcia has pointed out in the comments, for SHA-256 if the key is less than 64 bytes HMAC pads it with null bytes to length 64. So by adding a null byte to any key with less than 64 bytes we get the same result.

As @gsitcia also points out, for any key longer than 64 bytes, it is replaced with its hash. We can see this in action [here](https://tio.run/##pZDBasMwDIbvfgrv5HiU0mRdkxZy6BP0sKvHsBO1zrokxnZBfvpMNWwwttt0ENYvfT@yXIp2np4a55dlGN3sI7ej7hjr4czH9GZ1sAXKA@MUOgSggZgckMbblpsUIeSeh3jzU4bX/XCBEAtccSMu89zzj1t3FSsugtXV807ItQUs5HKFVHIyEfq/IRh5Vdmre9EKu63Cxig0e4VAtSmPCvcNFfWkUNNDU7c@Kyz10b6@K@x3jyTSeLkdN5T7E6WaAKOIgI1gzg9TLL5uct9dyt9i9S3m3z20PIt/0fcD/iSXTw). It is trivial to generate arbitrarily long collisions in this way.

Comment: The reason this works is that HMAC (with SHA-256) right pads the string with null bytes to 64 bytes (only if the key starts with <= 64 bytes. If it starts with more, it instead replaces the key with the hash of the key)

Comment: "The score of a robber answer is the sum of the number of bytes of the two strings with the hash collision, with the higher score being better" - perhaps you'd want to add some (a lot of) stuffer to your crack to increase its score...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Whoops, golf instincts. In any case, that seems strange. If the robber gets to choose, well in this case there's a cap but in general the largest possible collision may be arbitrarily large

Comment: @CursorCoercer You still have to find the crack.

Comment: @gsitcia I have no idea why hmac doesn’t place a SOH or another byte before all those NUL bytes…

Comment: There is a trivial infinite crack, set the first string to anything longer than 64 bytes, and set the second string to the sha-256 hash of the first string.

Comment: WHAT IS WRONG WITH HMAC!?! (sorry for the caps)